# How to use HideScheduler without creating task?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `action` that should be called from main thread and with `HideScheduler`.

How to call it from main thread syncronosly (without lifting to `async`)?

I've tried this code, but (unsurprisingly) it has deadlock on main thread.

```cs
void ExecuteWithHiddenScheduler(Action action)
{
  var task = new Task(action, TaskCreationOptions.HideScheduler);
  // execute task here
  
  // locks program, because this code is already executed in the main thread.
  task.RunSynchronously(MainThreadScheduler);
  task.Wait();
}
```